# Is it possible to prove induction over a setoid quotient?

Tags: category-theory, quotient-group, homotopy-type-theory

I've been playing with some homotopy stuff in category theory.

It's possible to define a "circle" with a sort of Scott encoding along the lines of `Definition circle := forall (S: Category) (pt: S), (pt <~> pt) -> S pt pt` (or at least I think this is correct.)

But this approach is hard to prove things about.

There is a well-known proof I don't understand at all that [induction is not derivable](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.26.957) in second-order dependent type theory. I think I might be running into similar issues but with quotients.

Is it possible to prove a sort of "setoid quotient induction principle?" I'm not even quite certain how to work out the types here.

I've started trying to rethink things in terms of an inductively defined "skeleton" that is then given an equivalence over it but I'm not sure this is the right approach to take.

I'm aware of the private inductive type hack but I was hoping setoids could avoid that sort of thing.

I'm also highly skeptical of my integers code. I wrote it as a quick hack to test if my "circle" works like a circle but I suspect my interpretation of things is basically wrong. If I've defined things right it should be the loop of circle isomorphisms that is isomorphic to the integers not circle morphisms right?

The full amateurish code I have so far.

```
(* Seems to make classes go faster? *)
Set Primitive Projections.
Unset Printing Primitive Projection Parameters.

Set Universe Polymorphism.
Set Program Mode.

Require Import Coq.Unicode.Utf8.
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.
Require Import Coq.Classes.SetoidClass.
Require Import Psatz.

Reserved Notation "A /~ B" (at level 40).

Reserved Notation "A ~> B" (at level 80).
Reserved Notation "A ∘ B" (at level 30).

Reserved Notation "A <~> B" (at level 80).
Reserved Notation "F 'ᵀ'" (at level 1).

Reserved Notation "F ! X" (at level 1).

Module Import Bishop.
  (* We need Bishop sets (AKA Setoids) not Coq's Type to make the Yoneda
     embedding on presheafs work properly.

     The technical jargon is that a Bishop Set is a 0-trivial groupoid,
     equality is the hom. *)
  #[universes(cumulative)]
  Class Bishop := {
    type: Type ;
    Bishop_Setoid:> Setoid type ;
  }.

  Module Export BishopNotations.
    Coercion type: Bishop >-> Sortclass.
    Notation "A /~ B" := {| type := A ; Bishop_Setoid := B |}.
  End BishopNotations.

  Definition fn (A B: Bishop) :=
    { op: @type A → @type B | ∀ x y, x == y → op x == op y } /~ {| equiv x y := ∀ t, x t == y t |}.

  Obligation 1.
  Proof.
    exists.
    all: unfold Reflexive, Symmetric, Transitive.
    - intros.
      reflexivity.
    - intros.
      symmetry.
      auto.
    - intros ? ? ? p q t.
      rewrite (p t), (q t).
      reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Add Parametric Morphism {A B} (f: fn A B) : (proj1_sig f)
      with signature equiv ==> equiv as fn_mor.
  Proof.
    intros.
    destruct f.
    cbn.
    auto.
  Qed.
End Bishop.

Module Import Category.
  #[universes(cumulative)]
  Class Category := {
    object: Type ;
    hom: object → object → Bishop
    where "A ~> B" := (hom A B) ;

    id {A}: hom A A ;
    compose {A B C}: hom B C -> hom A B -> hom A C
    where "f ∘ g" := (compose f g) ;

    compose_assoc {A B C D} (f: hom C D) (g: hom B C) (h: hom A B):
      (f ∘ (g ∘ h)) == ((f ∘ g) ∘ h );
    compose_id_left {A B} (f: hom A B): (id ∘ f) == f ;
    compose_id_right {A B} (f: hom A B): (f ∘ id) == f ;

    compose_compat {A B C} (f f': hom B C) (g g': hom A B):
      f == f' → g == g' → f ∘ g == f' ∘ g' ;
  }.

  Add Parametric Morphism (K: Category) (A B C: @object K) : (@compose _ A B C)
      with signature equiv ==> equiv ==> equiv as compose_mor.
  Proof.
    intros ? ? p ? ? q.
    apply compose_compat.
    apply p.
    apply q.
  Qed.

  Module Export CategoryNotations.
    Coercion object: Category >-> Sortclass.
    Coercion hom: Category >-> Funclass.

    Notation "f ∘ g" := (compose f g).
    Notation "A ~> B" := (hom A B).
  End CategoryNotations.
End Category.

Module Import Sets.
  Instance Bishop: Category := {|
    object := Bishop ;
    hom := fn ;
    id _ x := x ;
    compose _ _ _ f g x := f (g x) ;
  |}.

  Obligation 3.
  Proof.
    reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Obligation 6.
  Proof.
    rewrite (H _).
    apply (H3 _).
    rewrite (H0 _).
    reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Solve All Obligations with cbn; reflexivity.
End Sets.

Module Import Isomorphism.
  Section isos.
    Context `(K:Category).

    Section iso.
      Variable A B: K.

      #[universes(cumulative)]
      Record iso := {
        to: K A B ;
        from: K B A ;
        to_from: to ∘ from == id ;
        from_to: from ∘ to == id ;
      }.

      #[local]
      Definition hom := iso /~ {| equiv f g := to f == to g ∧ from f == from g |}.

      Obligation 1.
      Proof.
        exists.
        - split.
          all: reflexivity.
        - intros ? ? p.
          destruct p.
          split.
          all: symmetry.
          all: auto.
        - intros ? ? ? p q.
          destruct p as [p1 p2].
          destruct q as [q1 q2].
          split.
          + rewrite p1, q1.
            reflexivity.
          + rewrite p2, q2.
            reflexivity.
      Qed.
    End iso.

    Instance Isomorphism: Category := {
      object := object ;
      hom := hom ;
      id _ :=  {| to := id ; from := id |} ;
      compose _ _ _ f g :=
        {|
          to := to _ _ f ∘ to _ _ g ;
          from := from _ _ g ∘ from _ _ f
        |} ;
    }.

    Obligation 1.
    Proof.
      apply compose_id_left.
    Qed.

    Obligation 2.
    Proof.
      apply compose_id_right.
    Qed.

    Obligation 3.
    Proof.
      rewrite <- compose_assoc.
      rewrite -> (compose_assoc (to _ _ g)).
      rewrite to_from.
      rewrite compose_id_left.
      rewrite to_from.
      reflexivity.
    Qed.

    Obligation 4.
    Proof.
      rewrite <- compose_assoc.
      rewrite -> (compose_assoc (from _ _ f)).
      rewrite from_to.
      rewrite compose_id_left.
      rewrite from_to.
      reflexivity.
    Qed.

    Obligation 5.
    Proof.
      split.
      2: symmetry.
      all: apply compose_assoc.
    Qed.

    Obligation 6.
    Proof.
      split.
      + apply compose_id_left.
      + apply compose_id_right.
    Qed.

    Obligation 7.
    Proof.
      split.
      + apply compose_id_right.
      + apply compose_id_left.
    Qed.

    Obligation 8.
    Proof.
      split.
      + apply compose_compat.
        all:assumption.
      + apply compose_compat.
        all:assumption.
    Qed.
  End isos.

  Definition transpose {C:Category} {A B: C} (f: Isomorphism _ A B): Isomorphism _ B A :=
    {| to := from _ _ _ f ; from := to _ _ _ f |}.

  Obligation 1.
  Proof.
    apply from_to.
  Qed.

  Obligation 2.
  Proof.
    apply to_from.
  Qed.

  Module Export IsomorphismNotations.
    Notation "A 'ᵀ'" := (transpose A).
    Notation "A <~> B" := (Isomorphism _ A B).
  End IsomorphismNotations.
End Isomorphism.

Module Circle.
  #[local]
   Close Scope nat.

  (* Annoyingly a slightly byzantine definition is required to get some
  sort of induction *)
  Inductive circle := zero | compose (_ _ :circle) | clockwise | counterclockwise.

  Section inductive.
     Variables (S:Category) (pt:S) (loop: pt <~> pt).

     #[local]
      Fixpoint foldme (c: circle): S pt pt :=
       match c with
       | zero => id
       | compose f g => foldme f ∘ foldme g
       | clockwise => to _ _ _ loop
       | counterclockwise => from _ _ _ loop
       end.
  End inductive.

  (* Probably a simpler equality story *)
  #[local]
   Definition hom (A B: True): Bishop := circle /~
                     {| equiv x y := ∀ s base loop, foldme s base loop x == foldme s base loop y |}.

  Obligation 1.
  Proof.
    exists.
    all:intro;intros.
    - reflexivity.
    - symmetry.
      auto.
    - rewrite (H s _), (H0 s _).
      reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Instance Circle: Category := {
    object := True ;
    hom := hom ;

    id _ := zero ;
    compose _ _ _ := compose ;
  }.

  Obligation 1.
  Proof.
    apply compose_assoc.
  Qed.

  Obligation 2.
  Proof.
    apply compose_id_left.
  Qed.

  Obligation 3.
  Proof.
    apply compose_id_right.
  Qed.

  Obligation 4.
  Proof.
    rewrite (H s), (H0 s).
    reflexivity.
  Qed.

  Definition base: Circle := I.

  Definition loop: base <~> base := {|
    to := clockwise ;
    from := counterclockwise ;
  |}.

  Obligation 1.
  Proof.
    apply to_from.
  Qed.

  Obligation 2.
  Proof.
    apply from_to.
  Qed.

  Definition Circle_ind (c: Circle base base) (S : Category) (pt: S) (loop: pt <~> pt): pt ~> pt :=
    foldme S pt loop c.
End Circle.

Module Integers.
  Import Circle.

  Definition zero: base ~> base := id.
  Definition one: base ~> base := to _ _ _ loop.
  Definition neg_one: base ~> base := from _ _ _ loop.

  Instance Z: Category := {
    object := unit ;
    hom _ _ := (nat * nat) /~ {| equiv x y := fst x + snd y = fst y + snd x |} ;
    id _ := (0, 0) ;
    compose _ _ _ f g := (fst f + fst g, snd f + snd g) ;
  }.

  Obligation 1.
  Proof.
    exists.
    all:intro;intros;lia.
  Qed.

  Obligation 2.
  Proof.
    lia.
  Qed.

  Obligation 5.
  Proof.
    lia.
  Qed.

  Fixpoint neg (n: nat): base ~> base :=
    match n with
    | 0 => id
    | S n => neg_one ∘ neg n
    end.

  Fixpoint pos (n: nat): base ~> base :=
    match n with
    | 0 => id
    | S n => one ∘ pos n
    end.

  Definition to_circle (mn: (tt:Z) ~> tt): base ~> base := pos (fst mn) ∘ neg (snd mn).
  Definition from_circle (f: base ~> base): (tt:Z) ~> tt :=
    Circle_ind f Z tt {|
        Isomorphism.to := (1, 0) ;
        Isomorphism.from := (0, 1) ;
        to_from := eq_refl;
        from_to := eq_refl |}.

  Theorem from_to x: from_circle (to_circle x) == x.
  Proof.
    destruct x as [m n].
    induction m.
    - induction n.
      + reflexivity.
      + cbn in *.
        lia.
    - induction n.
      + cbn in *.
        lia.
      + cbn in *.
        lia.
  Qed.

  Theorem to_from x: to_circle (from_circle x) == x.
  Proof.
    induction x.
    - cbn.
      intros.
      apply compose_id_left.
    - intros s base loop.
      replace (Circle.foldme s base loop (compose x1 x2)) with (Circle.foldme s base loop x1 ∘ Circle.foldme s base loop x2).
      2: reflexivity.
      rewrite <- (IHx1 s base loop).
      rewrite <- (IHx2 s base loop).
      admit.
  Admitted.
End Integers.
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the group of a circle **is** addition over integers you can just directly define the circle group in terms of integers. This doesn't really help with proving things about circles but might give you a little help with other types defined in terms of circles such as loops and so on.